# Loss of precision when Interpolating between valid points

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

My test.csv contains many NaNs:

```
"Time","Y1","Y2","Y3"
"s","celsius","celsius","celsius"
"0.193","","",""
"0.697","","1",""
"1.074","","","-27"
"1.579","10","",""
"2.083","","5",""
"3.123","15","","-28"
"5.003","","",""
```

When I try to fill the missing data between valid points, using interpolate, it fills it with whole integers:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
df.loc[1:, "Y3"] = pd.to_numeric(df.loc[1:, "Y3"])
df.loc[1:, "Y3"] =  df.loc[1:, "Y3"].interpolate(method='linear').ffill()  #method='time' , method='index'

>>> print (df)
    Time       Y1       Y2       Y3
0      s  celsius  celsius  celsius
1  0.193      NaN      NaN      NaN
2  0.697      NaN        1      NaN
3  1.074      NaN      NaN      -27
4  1.579       10      NaN      -27  <<-----
5  2.083      NaN        5      -27  <<-----
6  3.123       15      NaN      -28
7  5.003      NaN      NaN      -28
```

I can fix the Nans at the start of the columns with bfill, but how can I fill the points between -27 and -28 with fractional values like -27.3, -27.6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you have strings in the first row.

`df.loc[1:, "Y3"] = pd.to_numeric(df.loc[1:, "Y3"])` doesn't change the dtype to a numeric one.

You should not put headers as a row, use a MultiIndex:

```
df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", header=[0, 1])
```

Then:

```
df['Y3'] = df['Y3'].interpolate(method='linear').ffill()
```

Output:

```
    Time      Y1      Y2         Y3
       s celsius celsius    celsius
0  0.193     NaN     NaN        NaN
1  0.697     NaN     1.0        NaN
2  1.074     NaN     NaN -27.000000
3  1.579    10.0     NaN -27.333333
4  2.083     NaN     5.0 -27.666667
5  3.123    15.0     NaN -28.000000
6  5.003     NaN     NaN -28.000000
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  Running it on the my dataset it seems that the interpolation doesn't happen until relatively few samples before the change.  For example, if there's 100 values between 27 and -28, then the interpolation starts about 10 rows before the -28  (ex. 27.1, 27.2..27.9).   Is there a way for it to interpolate with more precision such that the change is not all at the end?

Comment: I'm not sure to get what you mean, interpolation will happens between any two non-NaN values.